# Spock: How to properly share features between implementations of Specification

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I encountered an unfortunate aspect of Spock Framework (1.3-groovy-2.5), which I use for integration testing of a Gradle plugin.

**The code sample**

Parent class:

```
class ClassA extends Specification {

    def setupSpec() {
        System.out.println("In ClassA setupSpec()")
    }

    def "base feature"() {
        expect:
        true
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {

    @Override
    def setupSpec() {
        System.out.println("In ClassB setupSpec()")
    }

    def "extended feature"() {
        expect:
        true
    }
}
```

When I run tests in `ClassB`, both versions of `setupSpec()` are called:

```
In ClassA setupSpec()
In ClassB setupSpec()
```

Of course, if I call method via native Groovy ways:

```
class Main {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB classB = new ClassB()
        classB.setupSpec()
    }
}
```

Then I see only what is expected:

```
In ClassB setupSpec()
```

So, evidently, this is a Spock feature of some kind.

**Question**

In practice, what is the suggested way of inheriting from implementations of `Specification` while overriding setup logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented in [Fixture Method Invocation Order](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_invocation_order)

> If fixture methods are overridden in a specification subclass then
> setup() of the superclass will run before setup() of the subclass.
> cleanup() works in reverse order, that is cleanup() of the subclass
> will execute before cleanup() of the superclass. setupSpec() and
> cleanupSpec() behave in the same way. There is no need to explicitly
> call super.setup() or super.cleanup() as Spock will automatically find
> and execute fixture methods at all levels in an inheritance hierarchy.

The easiest way would be to just move the logic to another method that you can override.

```
class Base extends Specification {
  def setupSpec() {
    init()
  }
  
  def init() {
    println "foo"
  }

  def "let's try this!"() {
    expect:
    Math.max(1, 2) == 2
  }
}


class Sub extends Base {
  @Override
  def init() {
    println "bar"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, this is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: While it is possible, I agree with @kriegaex that you should probably look into refactoring/restructuring your specs so that this is not needed.

Comment: I thought about it. I am testing multiple custom Gradle plugins. One plugin extends another (internally), and they cannot be applied together. The setupSpec method applies the plugin. The spec itself tests plugin’s effects. Since plugins logically extend each other, it makes sense for specs to extend each other, but it is not possible (with current implementation) for setupSpec methods to extend each other.

Comment: You could still have a common abstract base spec with common tests and then just two or more derived specs which actually apply the plugin and test specific things. It is totally fine, if the only thing the one spec does is to apply the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

As [documented](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_invocation_order), fixture methods are not meant to override each other but to complement each other, i.e. they are all called in a specific, logical order. Like you said, this is a feature.

Hence, my answer is: There is no suggested way to **override** setup logic. Instead, the suggested way is to design your base and derived specifications in such a way that overriding is not necessary. I never had any problems to do so and hope you shall solve your problem easily too.

Your sample code is too schematic to say anything more, but basically think about fixture methods in base classes as responsible for to setting up and cleaning up fixture fields in there, while derived specs' fixture methods would take care of additional fixtures specific to those classes. In your example there also is a feature method in the base spec, which I find rather strange because it would be executed for the base spec itself and each time a derived spec is executed. I rather like to think of base specs as practically abstract (avoiding to add any feature methods to them and them being picked up by the test runner), but I am sure there are cases in which what you sketched above might also be helpful. I just cannot think of one now.